# Does writing boolean conditions "in full" compromise performance?

Tags: c++, c, performance, readability

For the sake of readability, I like to write boolean conditions "in full" in C/C++, e.g.:

`if (foo == true)` instead of `if (foo)` and `if (foo == false)` instead of `if (!foo)`.

Does this compromise performance?

Comment: Performance of the running program? Or of the poor maintenance programmer trying to read the logic through the extraneous noise?

Comment: The style that you use for the sake of readability hurts readability.

Comment: @MikeSeymour and @DanielDaranas: OK, I'm always willing to change my practices if they're not the best. Could you please explain why you find `if (!foo)` easier to read than `if (foo == false)`? I find that an ! is rather prone to being overlooked.

Comment: @mga Because the former can be read as fluent english : "if foo {...}" and "if _not_ foo {...}". This is assuming you have consistent variable/functions names (isEmpty, hasValue...)

Comment: It compromises readability, not performance.  With regards to the `!` being easy to overlook: that's only true if you eschew spaces.

Comment: Even in English, it's often more clear to state the comparison explicitly: "If it's true that ___, then I'm going to ___." Readability is in the eye of the beholder and is often the subject of religious debates. The OP wasn't asking for help deciding what's more readable, only whether his/her preferred style has any performance cost.

Comment: The issue is: you have a value of type `bool`.  If you insist on comparing values of type `bool` with `true` or `false`, then you have the problem that `foo == true` is also a value of type `bool`, so you actually need `(foo == true) == true`.  Except that that's also a `bool`, and so on, ad infinitum.

Comment: @Caleb Which is why the above are comments, and not answers.  (When I see something like `if ( foo == bool )`, it reads something like "the author doesn't understand the concept of a boolean type, or type systems in general, so beware of anything he's written.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Hard to put that much significant information into fewer characters... that's real efficiency.

Comment: @JamesKanze `if (someVariable) ...` is also frequently used with integer and pointer types, so sometimes writing the comparison explicitly can clarify things. Further, nobody has a problem with `if (someVariable == A_CONSTANT)...`, so it's hard to buy the argument that the explicit comparison is *so* verbose that it's hard to understand. More likely, the shorter version is a shibboleth that separates those deemed to be *in the know* from those who aren't. Honestly, if `if (foo == true)...` slows you down, then maybe you're the one who doesn't understand the concept of a boolean type.

Comment: @Caleb If `someVariable` isn't a `bool` in `if ( someVariable )`, then obviously, you want to compare it with something of the same type, in order to have an expression which has type `bool`.  This is a fundamental of the type system (which is somewhat broken in C++ because of the large number of implicit conversions---but well written code will be written as if the implicit conversions didn't exist).  No one has a problem with `someVariable == A_CONSTANT` because you need (logically, at least) an expression which has type `bool`.

Comment: @Caleb And `if ( foo == true )` doesn't slow me down; it just says to me that the author doesn't really understand the C++ type system, and so to beware of the code he has written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as straight C is concerned, the two forms *may* result in different machine code, which *may* affect performance.  Whether that performance difference *matters* will depend on what the code is doing and what your performance requirements are.

Using gcc 4.1.2 on SLES 10, I get slightly different machine code for `if ( foo == false )` vs `if ( !foo )`; given the following source code:

```
if ( foo == false )
{
  printf( "foo is false\n" );
}

if ( !foo )
{
  printf( "foo is 0\n" );
}
```

I get the following machine code (`gcc -S -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror`):

```
        movb    $0, -1(%rbp)      ;; foo = false
        cmpb    $0, -1(%rbp)      ;; if ( foo == false )
        jne     .L6               ;; {
        movl    $.LC2, %edi       ;;   
        call    puts              ;;    printf( "foo is false\n" );
.L6:                              ;; }
        movzbl  -1(%rbp), %eax    ;; if ( !foo )
        xorl    $1, %eax   
        testb   %al, %al
        je      .L8               ;; {
        movl    $.LC3, %edi       ;;   
        call    puts              ;;    printf( "foo is 0\n" );
.L8:                              ;; }
        movl    $0, %eax
```

*For this particular platform, compiler, code, and set of compiler options*, `if (!foo)` may wind up being a little slower than `if ( foo == false )`<sup>1</sup>.

Now, for the real question: does that performance difference (if it exists) matter?  For this particular program, absolutely not; the test occurs once over the lifetime of the program, and the time spent doing I/O will be considerably greater than the time spent performing the test.  In a different program where that test is being performed thousands or millions of times in a tight loop that's CPU bound, then it can matter quite a bit.

Code for readability *first*; the `if ( foo )` and `if ( !foo )` forms tend to be idiomatic for simple Boolean tests, and that's what most C and C++ programmers will expect to see.  Having said that, here's absolutely nothing wrong with writing `if ( foo == TRUE )` and `if ( foo == FALSE )` if you feel it conveys the intent of the code better (or if you decide to define `TRUE` as 0 and `FALSE` as 1 for whatever reason).

But *don't* make that decision based on performance *unless*:

1. You are failing to meet a hard performance requirement;
2. You have optimized your *algorithm* and data structures appropriately; and
3. Profiling shows *that particular statement* is the remaining bottleneck.

---

<sup>1.  Or not; it depends on how many cycles `xorl` and `testb` require vs `cmpb` and how much faster it is access register `%eax` directly than to compute `-1(%rbp)` and access the resulting location; for all I know it's a wash.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Assuming foo is a bool, it does not. It can be trivially optimized by the compiler.

However, this may not be the case if foo is a class, which can overload operators to do whatever it wants.

Comment: Now that would be fun.  Overload both `operator!` and `operator==(bool)`, with unrelated semantics.  (But I presumed he was talking about a `foo` of type `bool`.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested to know why there is a need for optimization by the compiler if `foo` is a bool?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Much fun will be had by all willing to chuck all convention and common sense...

Comment: @mga James has an explanation in his comment. Simply put, an if statement has an implicit `== true`, so `if (foo == true)` is actually like `if ((foo == true) == true)`

Comment: @JamesKanze Maybe someone wants `!` not to mean not, but to mean IMPORTANT!, so `!foo` makes foo even bigger.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Not an implicit `== true`(more like `!= false resp 0` anyway...), but an explicit conversion to bool. The difference is oft-times critical.

Comment: @Deduplicator I wasn't trying to be technically accurate to the assembly level.

Comment: @Deduplicator My comment wasn't trying to be technically accurate to the level level :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(foo == true)
```

Even though with evil overloads it can have different semantics and performance characteristics than the more idiomatic because less verbose

```
if( ! foo)
```

, wih sane types and reasonably efficient compilers, it should produce exactly the same native instructions.

If you allow malicious overloads, all bets are off anyway and you get the trouble you should expect.

Still, the above is not the canonical example for the folly of always adding an explicit comparison.
This would be:

```
if(foo)
if(foo == true)
if((foo == true) == true)
// ...
```

The disadvantages are:

- Needless verbosity, clarifying nothing.
- Danger of forgetting one `=`-sign, and so trying to assign the value.
- How much "clarifying" would be clear enough?
- If not using keywords for boolean constants, but the underlying 0 and 1, doing this risks comparison for equality to 1 where unequality to 0 is needed.

Be aware that in C, C++ and some related languages the same holds for pointers, integers (including character types) and most user-defined types as well.

Answer (score -4):

Assuming foo is a bool, it does not. It can be trivially optimized by the compiler.

However, this may not be the case if foo is a class, which can overload operators to do whatever it wants.

Comment: Why have you just copied @neilkirk's answer verbatim?

Comment: Copied from @Neil-Kirk.